# Derivative of softmax function in neural network

Tags: neural-networks

I'm trying to implement a neural network to classify images into classes. My output layer has 10 neurons so I apply a softmax function to this layer to convert output ($z = W^TX$) to probability. When I back propagate, I compute $\delta$ of softmax that is $\delta = (a - y^{target})*a*(1 - a)$ with $a$ is softmax output, $y^{target}$ is target $y$ and $*$ is element-wised multiplication and I'm using squared lost function. I know there's a problem at the derivative $a*(1 - a)$ but I can't correct myself.

I'm new to neural network so please go slowly.

Comment: It's already a little suspicious that you're using a squared loss function, as opposed to a cross entropy loss.

Comment: You should write everything explicitly (if there are two layers) $E = h(z,y_2), y_2 = f_2(W_2^T y_1),y_1 = f_1(W_1^T y_0)$ where $E$ is the error we'd like to minimize, $y_2$ is the output, $y_0$ the input, $z$ the desired output, and $W_i$ the weights we will optimize.